# google maps autocomplete unable to accept one specific address

Tags: maps, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Our website provides a taxi booking form for users to book taxis to or from Amsterdam Schiphol Airport. The issue lies in the unusual behavior of our two search boxes used for picking up and dropping off addresses. Previously, these search boxes worked perfectly, accepting any address inputted by users. However, for the past few days, they have been unable to accept one specific address: {Amsterdam Airport Schiphol (AMS), Evert van de Beekstraat, Schiphol, Netherlands} – the precise address of Amsterdam Schiphol Airport. Strangely, whenever a user enters the Schiphol Airport address, the value becomes empty, and this issue occurs only with this particular address.

To investigate the matter further, I created a new application solely for testing purposes: https://gdgdfgdgrretgd5.bubbleapps.io/version-test?debug_mode=true.

I would immensely appreciate your help and expertise.

I have already attempted to resolve the problem by using a new Google Maps API, but it did not produce any positive results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the business has been completely removed from Search and Maps as I had this email from a Google just this morning. It was for a review I'd left some time ago....

Your rating isn't posted

Amsterdam Airport Schip...

What happened
The place you posted about was removed from Google services like Maps and Search.

See content policy

What you can do

No action is needed from you. If the place is restored to Google services, your content will be restored automatically.